# Challenge in introducing reboot prompt during install failure and rollback

Tags: wix, windows-installer, installshield, failed-installation, reboot

we are facing issues with install failure and rollback which brings application to unstable state. With reboot done after failure and rollback, our application becomes stable. So to recommend user to do reboot, I am trying to reuse existing reboot prompt at end of install failure (Restart now or restart later message).

But in our installer , as ScheduleReboot is sequenced just after InstallFinalize , all the rollback actions between InstallInitialize and InstallFinalize are getting executed, but immediately after InstallFinalize all other actions are getting skipped(including ScheduleReboot) due to install failure

Also tried using "OnExit=error" attribute (sequence with negative value), but as ScheduleReboot is already sequenced, I am unable to invoke it again, and also ScheduleReboot doesnt have support with OnExit.

Please suggest any workaround on introducing reboot prompt at end of install failure (after SetupCompleteError dialog displayed).

Answer (score 0):

Create VBScript(or any other) custom action which will call ScheduleReboot action. e.g.

Session.DoAction("ScheduleReboot")

Set in-script execution to Rollback Execution for the above custom action and add condition as per your requirement.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! I have tried calling it in immediate action, but still not seeing reboot prompt at end of install error/cancellation. (Note - calling it during rollback is generating error, so marked it immediate and made sure it gets called before rollback)

Comment: what 's the error when calling in rollback execution?

Comment: Error 1720: There was a problem in executing the CA

Comment: Below is the extract from log file:(when running as immediate action)                     MSI (s) (34:50) [21:44:30:272]: Doing action: CallScheduleReboot
Action 21:44:30: CallScheduleReboot. 
Action start 21:44:30: CallScheduleReboot.
MSI (s) (34!50) [21:44:30:288]: Doing action: ScheduleReboot
Action 21:44:30: ScheduleReboot. 
Action start 21:44:30: ScheduleReboot.
MSI (s) (34!50) [21:44:30:288]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Adding MsiRebootActionScheduled property. Its value is '1'.
Action ended 21:44:30: ScheduleReboot. Return value 1.
Action ended 21:44:30: CallScheduleReboot. Return value 0.

Comment: Even when CA is run as in immediate mode, I see MsiRebootActionScheduled  getting set to 1, which is the purpose of ScheduleReboot CA. So will that matter if I run it as in immediate CA(before failure point of MSI for testing purpose to see whether ScheduleReboot is properly executed as expected to introduce reboot prompt) and not as an rollback CA?